# Keystone Service In Devstack Not starting

Tags: devstack

I installed devstack on ubuntu 16.04 running on virtual box. The first time everything came up and i was able to access all services. I turned off my VM and reopened it again and now the keystone service is not starting.

I have been reading lot of forums which say devstack installation is corrupted and i have to run stack.sh again. But isn't there any way to bring up the existing keystone service ? All the other services running.

I have tried "sudo systemctl start devstack@keystone.service" but it doesn't work.

Please provide a solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see below file after reboot?

ls -l /var/run/uwsgi/keystone-wsgi-public.socket

**s**rw-rw-rw- 1 stack stack 0 May  9 09:19 keystone-wsgi-public.socket

This is socket file and it should get created during startup.

Comment: YES. I CAN SEE IT.